# Question in proof of open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, quotient-spaces, open-map

[image]

Why is the mapping $\tilde A: X/N \to Y,\ \tilde A(x+N)=A(x)$ one to one (injective) and onto (surjective)?

$A$ is a continuous, linear map from a F-space $X$ to a topological vector space $Y$ and $A(X)$ is second category in $Y$.

Clearly it is surjective because we showed that $A(X)=Y$ and therefore $A$ is surjective. But I don't understand why $\tilde A$ is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because\begin{align}\tilde A(x+N)=\tilde A(y+N)&\iff A(x)=A(y)\\&\iff A(x-y)=0\\&\iff x-y\in N\\&\iff x+N=y+N.\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain the last implication? $x-y\in N$ means that $x-y=n$ for some $n \in N$. Why does this imply that $x+N=y+N$?

Comment: So, you are assuming that, for some $n\in\Bbb N$, $x+n=y+n$. Now, let $n^\star\in N$; I want to prove that $x+n^\star\in N$. But$$x+n^*=x+n-n+n^\star=y+n-n+n^\star=y+n^\star\in y+N.$$So, $x+N\subset y+N$ and, by the same argument, $y+N\subset x+N$.

Comment: I dont really understand. I am assuming that, $x-y \in N$, i.e. for some $n$ in $N$, $x-y=n$. And using this I want to prove that $x+N=y+N$

Comment: I was wrong! Let me start all over. So, you are assuming that, for some $n\in N$, $x=y+n$. Now, let $n^\star\in N$. Then$$x+n^\star=y+\overbrace{n+n^\star}^{\phantom N\in N}\in y+N.$$So, $x+N\subset y+N$ and, by the same argument, $y+N\subset x+N$.

Answer (score 1):

$\tilde {A} (x+N)=\tilde {A} (y+N)$ implies that $Ax=Ay$, so $x-y \in N$. This implies that $x+N=y+N$.